# Connect Mathematica to message broker - kafka, NATS or mosquitto

Tags: networking

I would like to subscribe to some topic of kafka or mosquitto in distributed system and do an real-time analyze of a data using Mathematica. Mathematica has [Channel-Based Communication](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Channel-BasedCommunication.html) using Pub/Sub methodology but it looks like strongly depends on Wolftam cloud. Also Mathematica doesn't have connectors to widespread brokers such kafka (see [SocketOpen](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketOpen.html) function).

Could you please expalain how to connect to these brokers (or any else) and subscribe to specific topic? Code example would be greater appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For broker that implements the MQTT protocol (mosquitto) Mathematica has **undocumented** package `MQTTLink` located in `SystemFiles/Links/MQTTLink` which works on publishing at least.

Toy example can be found [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1818557). Unfortunately, this example works only on publishing with my setup: Fedora 31, Mathematica 12 and mosquitto v.1.6.7 started locally. Related question is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211940/mqttlink-topicsubscribe-cannot-receive-messages).