# MQTTLink TopicSubscribe[] cannot receive messages

Tags: networking

Trying to start using undocumented package `MQTTLink` to interact with local mosquitto server. First of all I played with toy example pulled from this [link](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1818557):

```
Get@"MQTTLink`"

imAclientForExternal = CreateClient[];

ConnectClient[imAclientForExternal, "localhost:1883"];

TopicSubscribe[imAclientForExternal, "wolframTest", 
  "MessageReceivedFunction" :> (Print[
      ByteArrayToString[#3["Data"]]] &)];

TopicPublish[imAclientForExternal, 
  "wolframTest" -> "my personal message"];

TopicUnsubscribe[imAclientForExternal, "wolframTest"]
```

Publishing works fine but subscribing doesn't work at all. Nothing happens if a message is published in topic "wolframTest". Official util `mosquitto_sub` receives the test messages correctly.

`MQTTLink` is what I looked for for my purposes and subscribing should works unhesitatingly. Could you please help me with this example?